# elseでSyntaxError: invalid character in identifierとでてしまいます

Tags: python

PythonをWindowsで使っています。

else以降どうしてもひっかっかてしまいます。

"はあなんてや？"と出力したいのですが、"SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier" になってしまいます。

```
volume = 30
if volume < 50:
     print("はあなんてや？")
else：
　　print("聞こえとるわ")
```

Answer (score 0):

SyntaxError、つまり構文エラーは、プログラムの書き方に問題があるときよく現れます。

今回実行しようとしているプログラムが質問文にあるものと全く同じであるなら、`else` の後にあるコロンという記号が、半角のコロン `:` ではなく全角のコロン `：` になっているのが問題です。

私の環境で質問文のプログラムを動かすと、次のようにエラーが出ました。

```
  File "/tmp/example.py", line 4
    else：
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid character '：' (U+FF1A)
```

このエラーメッセージで示されているように、`else` のすぐあとの記号が Python によって認識できずエラーになっています。

ついでに、このエラーを直しても次は `print("聞こえとるわ")` の行の最初の方にあるスペースが半角スペース   ではなく全角スペース 　 になっているのでエラーになります。ここも直すと良いでしょう。